# UIAlertView displaying "translucent" after a short delay

Tags: animation, transparency, uialertview, alertview

I just noticed that my UIAlertView are displaying "in two steps" and it looks disturbing, it's like a display bug and not user friendly.

When displaying an alert view, it first displays "opaque" (not translucent) while animating, and then it becomes translucent so we can see through it.

As my background views are colorful, we really see the transition and that's not very user friendly.

Is there a way to set the alert views translucent from the beginning?

Thanks a lot, I hope I've been clear

Thomas

Comment: I have the same problem and I have not found the solution . Did you get the answer ?

Comment: Unfortunately no! Still the same issue...